# On wordpress set a custom number of posts in a category page

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a wordpress website and in the custom template for the category 10 I have this code:

```
<?php
function new_excerpt_length($length) {return 30;} add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 10 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size)?></div><div id="eu_post_category">
<h2><a class="roll-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></h2>
<h6><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h6> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This returns the last five posts in my category. But I do not want to lose the older posts. I want to have two buttons newer posts||older posts at the bottom in order to let the user see all the posts.

What I've tried: setting the max number in settings-> reading and to use this code in functions.php (with no results):

```
function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {
if ( is_category('10') )
set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', 5); // or use variable key: posts_per_page
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');
```

Thanks!

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<  when u click on new posts/older posts button get the page number(which is stored inside $paged varible) pass this inside the arguments

```
     <?php
        $args = array(
            'paged'            => $paged,
            'category'        => 10,
            'posts_per_page'  => 5,
            'post_status'     => 'publish');
        query_posts($args);
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                echo $post->post_title;
            }

       }
   ?>
```

for references: 
         http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts